# instantiating a template class which takes function pointers in constructor with different function signatures

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I have a template class which takes a function pointer in constructor. A method in the class will later call that function depending on a condition. Can I have 2 objects of that class, each instantiated with function pointers with different signatures? Simplified code is given below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class FUNC>
class Thread {
public:
    Thread(FUNC f1, int i)
      : f(f1), val(i) {};

    void run() {
        if (val == 1)
            f();
         else
            f(val); // here
     }
private:
     FUNC f;
     int val;
};

void print() {
    cout << "print" << endl;
}

void incr(int a) {
    cout << "incremented value is " << ++a << endl;
}

int main () {
    Thread<void(*)()> t1(print,1);
    t1.run();
    Thread<void(*)(int)> t2(incr,2);
    t2.run();
}
```

**run()** decides which function to call based on **val**. Both probable functions have different signatures. I'm getting the following compilation errors when doing this.

```
    testa.cpp: In member function 'void Thread<FUNC>::run() [with FUNC = void (*)()]':
    testa.cpp:33:   instantiated from here
    testa.cpp:16: error: too many arguments to function
    testa.cpp: In member function 'void Thread<FUNC>::run() [with FUNC = void (*)(int)]':
    testa.cpp:35:   instantiated from here
    testa.cpp:14: error: too few arguments to function
```

How do I do this? And is there a way in c++ using templates to do this in the first place?

Comment: Are `1` and `2` determined at compile time?  Or must they be runtime?  Why does `val` exist, because you want to support two signatures, or for some other reason?

Comment: What version of C++ are you using?

Comment: Im using c++98. 1 and 2 are determined at compile time. I'm using val only to distinguish between both types of template class instantiations.

Comment: @vibz: C++98?! You poor thing. I'll see if I can update my answer to reflect your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++98<sup>*</sup> the best approach is likely template class specialization for void functions (zero argument), and separately for unary (single argument) functions:

```
template<class FN>
class Thread;

// void functions
template <class RET>
class Thread<RET(*)(void)> {/*..*/}

// unary functions
template <class RET, class ARG>
class Thread<RET(*)(ARG)> {/*..*/}
```

The benefit to this approach is that you're not placing extra variables into a class that doesn't need them (the void function class). Also, due to the way our specialization is written, we can change the return type of `run` to be the same as the return type for the function pointer:

```
template <class RET>
class Thread<RET(*)(void)> {
public:
    typedef RET(*fptr_t)(void);
    Thread(fptr_t fptr) : f(fptr) {}

    RET run() {
        return f();
    }
private:
     fptr_t f;
};

template <class RET, class ARG>
class Thread<RET(*)(ARG)> {
public:
    typedef RET(*fptr_t)(ARG);
    Thread(fptr_t fptr, ARG arg) : f(fptr), val(arg) {}

    RET run() {
        return f(val);
    }
private:
     fptr_t f;
     ARG val;
};
```

And some tests:

```
Thread<void(*)()> t1(&print);
t1.run();
Thread<void(*)(int)> t2(&incr,2);
t2.run();
Thread<int(*)(int)> t3(&get_val, 42);
int return_value = t3.run();
std::cout << "t3 returned " << return_value << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
print
incremented value is 3
Returning 42
t3 returned 42
```

### [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a10b4c87f8a1825)

<sup>*which we've now learned you're using. And we're all very sorry for your luck</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I think that the fact that your `Thread` class forces the client to provide an `int` argument whether or not the function pointer accepts arguments at all points to a bit of a design flaw. What you want is for the client to only pass the arguments they need.

One way to accomplish this with templates is to use template specialization to capture which arguments are necessary, like so:

```
template<class...>
class Thread;

template <class RET, class... ARGS>
class Thread<RET(*)(ARGS...)> {/*..*/}
```

From there, the rest of the specialization almost writes itself. If you can handle the overhead, I recommend using a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instantiated with a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) so that you can bind the arguments received in `Thread`'s constructor. This is nice because it makes the held type in `Thread` consistent. Then you don't have to try some kind of run-time switching between two versions of `f()`

```
template <class RET, class... ARGS>
class Thread<RET(*)(ARGS...)> {
public:
    using fptr_t = RET(*)(ARGS...);

    Thread(fptr_t fptr, ARGS... args)
    {
       f = [fptr, args...]{fptr(args...);};
    }

    void run() {
        f();
    }
private:
     std::function<void(void)> f;
};
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/utaXdhnUc3H6FqeW)

Of course this code should become more complicated for a production environment, considering copying/moving of both `Thread` objects, but also move semantics for arguments to bind to the function pointer.

Comment: The alternative to `std::function` and a lambda would be a `tuple<Args...> args` and `std::apply`

Comment: @Caleth: Well said. Another alternative would be a custom lightweight functor class that doesn't need all the type erasure `std::function` provides.